# Microservices on Node.js with MicroMQ

Tags: node.js, express, microservices

I'm using MicroMQ to communicate between different services, and for main service it is ok, I received requests and then delegating them through RabbitMQ. I can see this message in queue but my microservice don't receive any messages. This is for main service:

controller:

```
export const create = async (req, res) => {
    await res.delegate('trade');
}
```

gatewayConfig:

```
const Gateway = require('micromq/gateway');
const config = require('../configServer');

export const gateway = new Gateway({
    microservices: ['platform', 'trade'],
    name: 'platform',
    rabbit: {
        url: "amqp://rihtavqi:AhKDUujmeC5hBUPb0zQb7qh7AgqnR5QG@lion.rmq.cloudamqp.com/rihtavqi"
    }
});

export const services = {
    trade: 'trade'
};
```

server.js

```
app.use(gateway.gateway.middleware());
```

this what I use in my main service. This is only place where I'm calling gateway...

And this is for microservice:
server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const gateway = require('./gateway/gatewayRoute');

const app = express();
const server = require("http").createServer(app);

gateway.start().then(() => {
    server.listen(constant.config.port, constant.config.host, async () => {
        loggingHelper.consoleLog("APP", `Server running on port ${constant.config.port} and on host ${constant.config.host}.....`);
        process.on("unhandledRejection", (reason, promise) => {
            loggingHelper.consoleLog("APP_ERROR", `Uncaught error in ${String(reason)}`, promise);
        });

});
```

route

```
const MicroService  = require('micromq/src/MicroService');
const loggingHelper = require('../app/helper/loggingHelper');

const orderService = require('../app/service/orderService');

const gateway = new MicroService({
        name: 'trade',
        rabbit: {
            url: "amqp://rihtavqi:AhKDUujmeC5hBUPb0zQb7qh7AgqnR5QG@lion.rmq.cloudamqp.com/rihtavqi"

        }
    }
);

gateway.post('/create', async (req, res) => {
    loggingHelper.consoleInfoLog("TRADE", "/create received.");
    res.json(await service.create(req));
});

module.exports = gateway;
```

Last one don't work. BTW my idea told me that .post() function is

> Unresolved function or method post()

I think problem is here. I trying different ways(creating Gateway(micromq/gateway) in microservice, tried to destructure MicroService but this all give me nothing)
all of this was creating by examples but it not works... And I cannot understand why? Somebody knows why?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about MicroMQ, but you could use the SMF framework to prototype microservices that are connected to RabbitMQ automatically:

https://medium.com/@krawa76/bootstrap-node-js-microservice-stack-4a348db38e51